# Java web application (jnlp) doesn't work

Tags: java, icedtea

I want to open a java web application ([Mirth Connect](https://www.mirth.com/)) on my Ubuntu machine. So following the tips on [this page](https://linux-tips.com/t/execute-jnlp-files-in-linux/252) I installed icedtea:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

and then executed the jnlp file I downloaded:

```
javaws webstart.jnlp
```

I then get this screen:

[image]

And whichever button I press (Yes, No, close) it constantly reloads this screen and refuses to proceed to the rest of the application.

On my Mac this application works perfectly well.

Does anybody know why this happens on Ubuntu, and how I can get it to work?

Comment: Is there any terminal output to the `javaws` command? What Java and IcedTea version is this? What's the output of `javaws -version` and `update-alternatives --list javaws`?

Comment: I also faced the same issue. I have openjdk installed in my laptop. Removed that and installed oracle jdk and things are working fine.

Comment: You seem to have redacted some important clues from your image and possibly ignored  the "For more information see" section of the output. Neither course of action would I recommend if you expect to receive a quality answer to your question. My gut reaction without being able to see the domain being utilized is just don't! `xkill` the window.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri - Yes.. That finally solved it! If you add your suggestion as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have openjdk installed, remove it and install the oraclejdk. It worked for me. You can maintain multiple versions of jdk and switch between each and make them active.

Comment: No need to uninstall openjdk. Good howto is here: www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04